# "Include virtual' as in Classic ASP for PHP is possible?

Tags: php, asp-classic, include

Is there a similar command in php simulating command in Classic ASP "include virtual" that can be applied in the command 'file' or 'include' to guide the opening of files?

I use a Windows Host not Apache.

Comment: You may provide some additional information for those of us, who never used asp.

Comment: @KingCrunch - as much as I dislike w3schools, they have a reasonable writup of what 'include virtual' is (as compared with 'include file'): http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP's `#include` directive allows `file` or `virtual` options, which include files using a path either relative to the current file or relative to the site root, respectively.

(More info can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp) (and yes, I dislike w3schools as much as the next guy here, but it was the clearest explanation I could find in a hurry; feel free to replace it if you know a better one)

PHP's `include()` function (and `include_once()`, `require()` and `require_once()`) doesn't differentiate this way. If you want to include a file using a directory relative to the virtual server root, you need to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in your include path. ie:

```
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\myfile.php";
```

See the PHP manual page for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php